# C# WPF DataGrid Event Handler for reading-in editable ComboBox values in a column

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I'm looking for an event handler that will pass an updated value from an editable combobox (meaning text-entry is also a value that can be input, as well as a selectable-item from the dropdown, in some rows).

I also need to obtain the values of other columns in the same row when the combobox is updated.

Example code on how to obtain the values would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `TextBoxBase.TextChanged` event:

```
private void ComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    string text = comboBox.Text;
    IEnumerable items = comboBox.Items.OfType<ComboBoxItem>();
    ComboBoxItem selectedItem = comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
    Debug.WriteLine(text);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="ComboBox_TextChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem>first</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>second</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>third</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: That looks like it's working as it should, but also outputs the variable "text" as the grid is being populated. Is there anyway to skip over this function as the grid is being populated?

Also, is there a way to get the value of another column using this method?

Comment: Grid being populated, meaning as the grid is loading the values according to their bindings.

I actually was able to do that using "if (GRID.SelectedItem == null) return;"

Comment: This method works for the most part, but I'm experiencing an issue when actually entering text into the editable textbox. When typing in the box, the input is interrupted, because the function is called with each keystroke.

Comment: @ChristopherSwierczynski: It's supposed to be. You should not do anything that moves the focus away from the TextBox in the event handler.